# CString Unable to Load Japanese string from Resource

Tags: c++, string, mfc, cstring

I don‘t know its a valid question or not.

I am working on one project where I want to Load a Japanese string from a string Table.

But I am unable to do that.
When I am Loading String Resource in `CString` it Load Japanese Char as `???????????`.

I am using following code to Load String.

`CString msg;`

`msg.LoadString(JAPANESE_STRING_RESOURCE_ID)`

and in String Table I have added string as

`JAPANESE_STRING_RESOURCE_ID  128 "ありがとう　ございます。"`

I am not able to trace for the same.

Can any one help me out on this?

Comment: Did you compile everything for UNICODE?

Comment: no I have compile all in Multibyte setting of VS2010

Comment: Try using wide characters to read the string.

Comment: Ankit B In that case, is your Windows switched to the Japanese language? I think, multibyte builds will only work for the local language and its encoding, like SHIFT-JIS for Japanese or whatever. You should be working with wide characters for making internationalized applications that display text in multiple languages.

Comment: And, by the way, `.rc` files have to be stored as wide character text files. The Microsoft resource compiler doesn't understand UTF-8 or anything of the sort.

Comment: @Kaz Yes I have switched to japanese language and my machines local language is also Japanese,  but the string i got is same as I mentioned

Comment: @Smac89 I tried using  wide char too but same result.

Comment: @AnkitB Possibly the resource compiler is not handling the data right. Another consideration may be the font of the dialog boxes where you're trying to display this.

Comment: If you break into the code with the debugger, can you see the contents of the `CString` object after it is loaded with the resource, and how does it display?

Comment: @Kaz Thank you for your help About Windows Language and Encoding I am able to get the string now for machine with Japanese Language as Local Language

Comment: My advise would be: Convert everything to Unicode. If it is only a small partial problem you can use CStringW...

Comment: @xMRi Sorry I cant do that because my whole application is for Multibyte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, using Unicode on project helps with this kind of troubles. If you definitely need to use Multibyte in your project, you still can use Unicode CSrting-s - it's CStringW. This can help:

```
CStringW msg;
msg.LoadString(JAPANESE_STRING_RESOURCE_ID)
```